# Tooltip is not getting detected in angular

Tags: fullcalendar, tooltip

I am using FullCalendar 6.1.6 and angular 12 and  I am using the below  code for tooltip. As per doc (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo)

```
eventDidMount: function(info)
 {
 var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
 title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
 placement: 'top',
 trigger: 'hover',
 container: 'body'
});
}
```

As angular , is not able to detect Tooltip class (Cannot find name 'Tooltip) .
Not sure which class to import .

I am looking for a module or a class from where I can import tooltip method .
I have installed bootstrap , ng-bootstrap .

Comment: As per the Codepen attached to the demo you linked to, the Tooltip functionality relies on https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js and https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js, plus the custom CSS provided in the pen itself. Did you not look at the soure code of the demo?